# Spring Boot embedded Jetty 403 error

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, struts, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm having a strange issue on my webApp that when I enter url I get immediatly this error

> HTTP ERROR: 403 Problem accessing /PayingServiceWeb/. Reason: Forbidden

But if i enter manually the the name of the page frontpage.jsp to the URL it will start my struts action and move me forward. I just don't understand why it doesen't start automatically when I enter the page. I'm pretty noob with Jetty and Struts so that can be an issue...

The program used to use EJB beans, but they all have been removed and replaced with Jpa API. Some files contain some EJB names still.

I'm using Jetty version jetty-9.2.19 and Struts 1.2.9 and Spring Boot on my project.

Here is my main module pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>PayService</groupId>
<artifactId>PayService</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>PayService</name>

<properties>
    <PayServiceJava-legacy.version>${version}</PayServiceJava-legacy.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>fi.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>legacy-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<description>PayService</description>

<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>service</groupId>
            <artifactId>JdbcBicProvider</artifactId>
            <version>${JdbcBicProvider.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>

<modules>
    <module>../PayServiceJava</module>
    <module>../PayServicePersistenssi</module>
    <module>../PayServiceSessionEJB</module>
    <module>../PayServiceSingletons</module>
    <module>../PayServiceTehtava</module>
    <module>../PayServiceWeb</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And here is my web module pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>PayServiceWeb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>PayServiceWeb</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>PayService</groupId>
    <artifactId>PayService</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../PayService</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>PayService</groupId>
        <artifactId>PayServiceJava</artifactId>
        <version>${PayServiceJava-legacy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>PayService</groupId>
        <artifactId>PayServiceSessionEJB</artifactId>
        <version>${PayServiceJava-legacy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>PayService</groupId>
        <artifactId>PayServiceTehtava</artifactId>
        <version>${PayServiceJava-legacy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>PayService</groupId>
        <artifactId>PayServiceSingletons</artifactId>
        <version>${PayServiceJava-legacy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts</artifactId>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>common.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>JdbcBicProvider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>common</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonWebJava-legacy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>PayserviceWeb</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/struts-config-mp.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>validate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>
    Alustus</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Alustus</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    payservice.servlet.Alustus</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>
    ParametrienPaivitys</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ParametrienPaivitys</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    payservice.servlet.ParametrienPaivitys</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Alustus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Alustus</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ParametrienPaivitys</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.parametrit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>frontpage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>payservice.webservices.authentication.listener.WebServiceKayttajaRequestListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And here is part of my Struts-config.mp.xml looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

  <struts-config>
  <form-beans>
  <form-bean name="loginForm" type="payservice.form.LoginForm" />   
  <form-bean name="payForm" type="payservice.form.PayForm"/>

  <global-forwards>

  <forward name="mp.start" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/payservice/etusivu.jsp"/>
  <forward name="login" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp"/> 
  <forward name="mp.start_payment" path="/mp/start_payment.do?method=show"/>
  <forward name="mp.logout" path="/user.do?method=logout" />  
  <forward name="error" path="/error.jsp"/>

 </global-forwards>
```

```
<action path="/login" 
            type="payservice.LoginActions" 
            parameter="method" 
            scope="request" 
            name="loginForm" 
            input="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" 
            validate="true">
        <forward name="valid" path=".mp.frontpage" />
        <forward name="relogin" path=".mp.frontpage" />                      
        <forward name="error" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />                    
    </action>  

    <action path="/payservice" 
         type="payservice.MainPageActions"
         parameter="method" >
        <forward name="base" path=".mp.frontpage"/>            
        <forward name="menu" path=".mp.menu" />
        <forward name="topic" path=".mp.frontpage" ></forward> 
    </action> 


<action path="/mp/start_payment" type="payservice.BeginNewPaymentAction" name="preparepaymentForm" scope="session" validate="false" parameter="method">
  <forward name="start" path=".mp.payment_start"/>
  <forward name="make_new_payment" path=".mp.new_payment"/>
</action>

<action path="/user" type="payservice.LoginActions" 
            parameter="method" 
            scope="request" 
            name="loginForm" 
            validate="false">

        <forward name="out" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/logout.jsp" />   
        <forward name="sessionOut" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionOut.jsp" />                 
        <forward name="error" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />                              
    </action>
```

```
   <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
    <set-property property="definitions-debug" value="0"/>
    <set-property property="definitions-parser-validate" value="true"/>
    <set-property property="definitions-parser-details" value="0"/>
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/config/tiles-defs-mp.xml"/>
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true"/>
</plug-in>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was pretty retarded. I had forgotten to to do a maven build package for the project. After I had done it, it started to work.